# Apache mod_rewrite to replace sub-folder with different for all non script URIs

Tags: mod-rewrite

My objective is to redirect non-jsp URLs to different subfolder

#### Browser URL

- http://mydomain.com/site-Xghthhg/css/styles1/layouts.css
- http://mydomain.com/site-Xghthhg/jslibs/jquery/jquery.js
- http://mydomain.com/site-Xghthhg/jslibs/jquery/plugins/jd/jquery.jd.js

#### Proxy to

- http://mydomain.com/map/css/styles1/layouts.css
- http://mydomain.com/map/jslibs/jquery/jquery.js
- http://mydomain.com/map/jslibs/jquery/plugins/jd/jquery.jd.js

#### httpd.conf

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.+\.jsp) 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site-(.*)/^(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^/site-(.*)/^(.*)$ /map/$2 [P]
```

I don't understand why it is not working!

Comment: Finally with help of [regEditor]http://myregexp.com/ I fixed it.  `RewriteRule ^/site-(.*?)/(.*)$  /map/$2 [P,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using REQUEST_URI for the first line.  You don't need the second line.
Finally, your regex is invalid, the caret means "match the beginning" so it makes no sense to use it in the middle of the regex.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+\.jsp)
 RewriteRule ^/site-([^/]*)/(.*)$ /map/$2 [P]
```

Here, I do use a caret in the middle but inside the [] context, caret has a different meaning: match any character *except* the following (so [^/]* matches a string of characters that are not slashes).

Comment: I changed to above configuration, but it doesn't includes it subfolders. For example:   rewrite '/site-cWF8OQ/styles/yuicontainer.css' -> '/map/yuicontainer.css'

Comment: the first part of the regex was being too greedy.  changed to match only non-slash characters.  try now.